# can't connect to local svn server (visual svn server)

Tags: svn

i have some trouble with visual svn server. I cannot reach any repositories with visual svn command client, tortoise or with any browser on my own machine.

The url from the server is: http://svnserver:10000/svn/ (example)
i created a repository with the visual svn server gui, but i can't reach it with any svn client. I get the following error if i try "svn info" or "svn ls":
"Could not resolve hostname `foo': The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for."

I cannot even ping svnserver.
I cleared my local dns cache, but no luck.